# Помогите разобраться с SQL запросом к ClickHouse

Tags: sql, clickhouse

Всем привет! Наткнулся на такую задачку:

Даны две таблицы в Clickhouse, в каждой из которых по 100 млн+ строк и возможны дубликаты. Каждый день обновляется около 1 млн продуктов (то есть на 2 порядка меньше, чем строк в таблице).

```
CREATE TABLE products (
    product_id Int32, 
    product_name String, 
    brand_id Int32, 
    seller_id Int32, 
    updated Date
    ) ENGINE = ReplacingMergeTree ORDER BY product_id
```

```
CREATE TABLE remainders (
    date Date, 
    product_id Int32, 
    remainder Int32, 
    price Int32, 
    discount Int32, 
    pics Int32, 
    rating Int32, 
    reviews Int32, 
    new Bool
    ) ENGINE = ReplacingMergeTree ORDER BY (date, product_id)
```

Напиши 3 причины, по которым следующий запрос выполняется медленно (5 секунд) и предложи быструю версию запроса (<0.1 секунды :), без изменений архитектуры таблиц (не надо предлагать "добавить индексы") и дающую такой же результат:

```
select product_id 
from products final 
join remainders final using(product_id) 
where updated=today() and date=today()-1
```

Сижу с ней уже пару дней, но решение что-то пока не приходит. Буду благодарен за любые полезные мысли или полноценное решение.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если речь идет об одном 1%, можно попробовать сделать так

```
select x.product_id 
from (select product_id from products final where updated=today() 
   ) x 
join (select product_id from remainders final where date=today()-1
   ) y 
 using(product_id)
```

можно надеяться на сокращение на 2-4 порядка :)

Comment: Спасибо большое, это действительно должно ускорить выполнение запроса. Пожалуй пойду читать основы SQL, ваш ответ выглядит таким простым и понятным, даже стыдно, что я так долго над этим сидел.

Answer (score 0):

Ох блин увидел final и сразу вспомнил что он достаточно ресурсоемкая конфетка. Желательно конечно воздерживаться от его использования. В идеале бы сделать предфильтрацию а только потом join, на крайняк попробовать сделать подзапросы

Comment: да, это точно, FINAL очень затратный и хорошо бы отказаться от него, но я не понимаю, как это сделать так, чтобы запрос возвращал тот же результат

Comment: ох ну тут я бы предложил обратить внимание на агрегацию в купе с подзапросами. Я так для примера накидал, не уверен что будет работать но мысль надеюсь верно передал (сори я хз как тут в комментах нормально код кидать)

SELECT 
    p.product_id
FROM 
(
    SELECT 
        product_id, 
        MAX(updated) AS last_updated
    FROM products
    WHERE updated = today()
    GROUP BY product_id
) p
JOIN 
(
    SELECT DISTINCT product_id
    FROM remainders
    WHERE date = today() - 1
) r USING (product_id)